# How do I change from lower case to upper case in MASM 32?

Tags: assembly, masm

I have this code which according to me should switch every character to its upper form, I already check the bit mask and it's fine. However when I print the string it's still in its lower case form.

```
            .MODEL SMALL
            .STACK 
                    .DATA

MEN         DB      'abcd'


        .CODE

            ORG     100H
MAIN        PROC    FAR

            LEA     BX, MEN+1
            MOV   CX, 20

OTRO:       MOV     AH,[BX]
            CMP      AH, 61H 
            JB          OTRO2
            CMP     AH, 7AH
            JA         OTRO2
            AND     AH, 11011111B 
            MOV     [BX], AH

  OTRO2:    INC        BX
            LOOP    OTRO
            MOV     AX, 4C00H
            INT       21H

  MAIN      ENDP

  END     MAIN
```

Answer (score 2):

You're jumping over the first character,

```
LEA     BX, MEN+1
```

and loop beyond the length of the string,

```
MOV   CX, 20
```

but other than that it seems to be working at this end. How are you printing the string? it's not in the supplied code.

Comment: Oh I damn that plus one was for debuggin reason, I'm printing it with int 21

Comment: How are your segments set up? I think you might be addressing the data segment wrong.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about :(

Comment: If you don't know what segments are, put your string inside .code instead, after your code. Will probably make it work.